# Direction of induced emf and induced current

Tags: magnetic-fields

I'm currently learning about Lenz's Law in physics, and I was confused about determining direction of induced emf.

I understand that when I have a magnetic field that is changing in one direction, a current will be induced in a direction as to oppose the changing magnetic field. How does the induced emf play into this? Does the induced emf always occur in the same direction as the induced current?

Thank you!

Comment: The induced current will flow in whatever direction is required to oppose the *change* in the magnetic field. That's not quite what you said above, so I just wanted to clarify. The induced EMF is going to be whatever is required to make the induced current flow in the appropriate direction.

Comment: @Nick Thank you for the correction. When you say the induced EMF is going to be whatever is required to make the induced current flow in the appropriate direction, will they always be in the same direction then? I'm confused about how their directions are related.

Comment: EMF is a potential difference: I hesitate to associate a "direction" to it. All you can say is that the induced current flows in some direction according to Lenz's law. A current flows because there is a potential difference between two points in a circuit and the direction of the flow is from the point of high potential to the point of low potential.

Answer (score 1):

Emf is a scalar quantity because it is defined in terms of work done (scalar) per unit positive charge.
As such the name electromotive force is not a good one as the use of the word force might imply that emf has a direction.

When there is an induced emf then a force will act on a charge and the direction of that force on a positive charge will give you the direction of the induced (conventional) current if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a horizontal conductor of length L moving perpendicular to a uniform magnetic field B with uniform velocity v. For simplicity let's assume the conductor, it's direction of motion and the magnetic field are all mutually perpendicular.

Now, for a charged particle moving in a magnetic field, the force on the particle is given as

F = q(v×B)

Now, the electrons in the conductor move as shown and this creates a lower potential at side A than at side B.*(This is actually known as **Hall Effect**)*

[image: Hall Effect]

*You can also look up Flemings right hand rule.*